# Use separate S3 buckets for separate sites in a multisite environment

Tags: multisite, amazon

We are trying setup 4 different sites using a single WordPress instance. Our challenge is that we would like each to have their own S3 Bucket, however when it comes to users the avatar image of the user will be stored on a network level other than that the media files are separate from one another.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

welcome :)
We really need more information. A list of what you have tried and would like to try would be helpful as well. Additionally, it would be good to know whether you are wanting to use the AWS S3 Bucket to store only media or more.

From a developer standpoint:
Multi-site implementations give each site an ID. You can get the site's ID with the function `get_current_blog_id()` and then use that to tell your plugin which hard-coded AWS S3 Bucket to use.
Alternatively, you can make the plugin have an options page where you can add the Bucket credentials and let it handle authentication from there.

Since, normally, plugin settings and media libraries are not shared between network sites you would likely be able to find a plugin that will suit your needs. This one seems popular: https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/